# How to display manufacture image with product in categories page?

Tags: magento-1.7, image

I am working with magento 1.7. I added a manufacture image in my product and i wish to display it in the categories page with the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you've created an Image attribute in the backend for this specific image, let's say `manufacturer_image` you can add this attribute to the collection used on the category product list by modifying the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer`, method `prepareProductCollection` on line 116.

Change

```
$collection
   ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
   ->addMinimalPrice()
   ->addFinalPrice()
   ->addTaxPercents()
   ->addUrlRewrite($this->getCurrentCategory()->getId());
```

to

```
$collection
   ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
   ->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer_image')
   ->addMinimalPrice()
   ->addFinalPrice()
   ->addTaxPercents()
   ->addUrlRewrite($this->getCurrentCategory()->getId());
```

It would be better to extend  the class in your own custom extension and just overwrite the part you need.

I've never used this to add a product but did it before for some other data I needed in that collection eliminating the need to load the whole Product object (`Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(...);`)

Comment: in any file can i edit that ?

Comment: In case you don't want to extend the file from your own extension you can copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php` and edit it there

Comment: Thanks. I have an other idea that i will applicate. If a added all manufactures image file in the image folder and i have a drop down list attribute with manufactures name. Every product are a manufacture name. I wish to display every manufacture image according manufacture name. For example, if i have Samsung as manufacture that display me the Samsung manufacture image.

Comment: Ah well in that case add your solution as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: i need help to applicate it

Comment: What you're asking for is ready to go code which would take quite some time to write. I would suggest trying to make a start yourself, see where you get stuck and then post a specific question on that

Comment: I try this but i have a problem : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11170/error-when-i-display-a-manufacture-image-with-condition-if

Answer (score 0):

After you load the product image with the collection you can call in the list.phtml template
like $_product->getManufacturerImage()