# Error when i display a manufacture image with condition if

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, error

I am in this file : \app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\product\list.html
I try to display a manufacture image before image product according an manufacture attribute text.
For example if the attribute is empty that must display me this image empty.png added in images in my template.
i add this code before :

```
      <?php
      if (strcmp($_product->getAttributeText('manufacture'),""))==0){?>
      <div class="logo-image"><img class="pr-img" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/arrow-about.png');?>" width="75" height="75"/></div>
      <?php ;} ?>
```

without the condition if it works very well but now i have this error :

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL)
I have this error

Comment: Try `empty()` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test, a closing parenthesis has to be removed

```
 <?php
  if (strcmp($_product->getAttributeText('manufacture'),"")==0){?>
  <div class="logo-image"><img class="pr-img" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/arrow-about.png');?>" width="75" height="75"/></div>
  <?php ;} ?>
```

For improved the readability of your code, use this syntax in phtml file

```
<?php if(you test): ?>
    <p>your html code <?php echo var ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

- replace { by :
- replace } by endif or endwhile, endfor, ...
- ; is not usefull before php end tag (?>)

To test if a string is empty in php the most appropriate method is to use the [empty()](http://php.net/empty) method

Your code with all changes

```
<?php if(empty($_product->getAttributeText('manufacture')): ?>
  <div class="logo-image">
    <img class="pr-img"
         src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/arrow-about.png') ?>"
         width="75" height="75"/>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>
```